# Running command in Cronjob in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, cron

I'm trying to run some commands upon every system boot in cronjob but it doesn't seem to be working, so far i have installed cron in Arch, enabled and started it with

```
systemctl enable cronie
systemctl start cronie
```

Then i went into a new crontab using

```
crontab -e
```

And added the following lines:

```
@reboot /bin/xbindkeys
@reboot /bin/setxkbmap -layout gb
```

I need these two commands to run on startup ever time, the first command is to start xbindkeys, and the second is to set my keyboard layout to GB layout. When i rebooted my system the crontab didn't seem to do anything, id appreciate if i can get some help, Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the output of:

```
journalctl -xe | grep CRON
```

```
Aug 26 14:30:48 archlinux crond[329]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.5.5)
Aug 26 14:30:48 archlinux crond[329]: (CRON) INFO (Syslog will be used instead of sendmail.)
Aug 26 14:30:48 archlinux crond[329]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 5% if used.)
Aug 26 14:30:48 archlinux crond[329]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Aug 26 14:30:49 archlinux CROND[423]: (user1) CMD (/bin/xbindkeys)
Aug 26 14:30:49 archlinux CROND[424]: (user1) CMD (/bin/setxkbmap -layout gb)
Aug 26 14:30:49 archlinux CROND[348]: (user1) CMDOUT (Cannot open display "default display")
Aug 26 14:30:49 archlinux CROND[348]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user user1
Aug 26 14:30:50 archlinux CROND[349]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user user1
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that these commands look like an XY-problem, my best bet is that the cron job is executed too soon (of at all). Did you check the systemd journal?

Comment: I have edited my answer with the output of journal -xe | grep CRON

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're using the wrong tool for the job here; instead of `cron`, you could put a script in `/etc/init.d`. If you're on Debian, you can find some help at `/etc/init.d/README`.

Comment: im on Arch Linux

Comment: -1 OP uses systemd, not System V.